# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:63591

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

I have been working on this for a few days and exhausted everything. I have searched throughout stackoverflow but everything I tried it did not work.

I am running it on a local machine and using a SQL Management Studio 2016 as my SQL database.

What I have done to try to fix this is:

- Turned off all my firewall settings.
  [image: image title]
- Opened the port on my network. [image: image title]
- Checked to see if the code was right. [image: image title]
- Used `netstat -ab` to check the ports, and it showed the port I was running was on `0.0.0.0:63591` under SqlServer but not under `127.0.0.1` (Localhost) like it should be. [image: image title]
- I have went to IIS and enabled browsing of directories. [image: image title]
- I created a default document called Food.aspx (Read in a post to try it) and it did not work. [image: image title]
- I tried to change the identity to local admin user account but all it
  was said that that the password was invalid.

[image: image title]

- I have checked every link, and tried all the options I could find. Lastly, it was giving me a 500 error which means server error. Looked at the stack trace and it was the error below. 
  [image: image title]
- I tried to telnet it and does not work
  [image: image title]

If you could help me that would be great

Comment: You forgot to explain what your server is, what you client is, how they are communicating. Please read [ask] if you want help

Comment: Wait, do you have SQL server configured to run on port 63591 or your web app to run on 63591 in IIS? This is all very confusingly put together.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Presentation is king! Some of your images are very big. Cropping them would be a big help to readers.

Comment: I am running it on a localhost. My web app is configured to run on port 65391

Comment: have you tried even just "telnet localhost 65391" to see what happens? If it can't connect, it's 99% sure a problem with IIS (config, app pool started, etc.)

Comment: "Could not open the host, on port 65391: connect failed." So should I install IIS again?

Comment: I don't think it's an IIS installation problem. It sounds more like you think IIS is running on 65391 but it's not. You've gotta find out why it's not. We can't help you with that with the information you've given us.

Comment: What information would you need. Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow and new at this.

Comment: From your `netstat` image, the Sql Server is running on port 63591, which is fine.  From the image showing the 500 error, your IIS is also working fine.  What seems to be the problem is that you're trying to connect to the Sql Server in your code using an `HttpClient` object, which is not going to work, that's not how you connect to a database.  As for why your Sql Server rejected a direct telnet connection, that's odd.  Are you sure Sql Server was still running on that port when you tried `telnet`?

Comment: My sql server is running on port 1433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your database instance are running? Check it in configuration manager of your SQL Server and also the default port.

[image]
[image]

After, compare with your port number in connection string of your web config.

```
<connectionStrings>
<clear/>
<add name="xxxxx" connectionString="metadata=res://*/xxxx.csdl|res://*/xxx.ssdl|res://*/xxx.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=yyy;Password=yyyy;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/></connectionStrings>
```

So, after I debugged your code I found the problems in your solution.

**1-**The first cause of this problem is a **"Self referencing loop detected for property"**, because your are trying to serialize the Entity Framework object directly with public IQueryable GetFoods(). Since Food have MealFood and the MealFood have a reference back to Food, it cannot be serialized.

The solution is to add in your Global.asax this code `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;`

your method will be like this :

```
protected void Application_Start(){ GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; }
```

Here we need to define global setting for JSON.Net serializer to ignore circular references.

**2-**The second problem is **"The entity or complex type 'Model' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"**.

To resolve this you can create a Pseudo Class of your Food Class like this
one:

```
public class PseudoFood
{
public int FoodID { get; set; }
public string FoodName { get; set; }
public int Calories { get; set; }
public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

after it's possible to query your DB with this method.

```
public IQueryable<PseudoFood> GetFoods()
{    
      return (from a in db.Foods
                    orderby a.FoodName descending
                    select new PseudoFood()
                    {
                        FoodName = a.FoodName,
                        FoodID = a.FoodID,
                        Calories = a.Calories,
                        Notes = a.Notes
                    }
             ).AsQueryable();    
}
```

returning PseudoFood "IQueryable" and finally retrieve your record.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the SQL server is running and has the port 1433. I have another project in the same Application Pool that runs fine and using the same database. What seems to not be working is when I am trying to use a web api to send a get request to gather all foods in a table. It gives the 500 error and says it has refused all connections

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5CLvnP8r, It is just a simple one page app to test. For your previous question about the port number in the connection string. All that is where your XXXX are is the "MealPlanner" which is the ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Comment: I know, I changed it back to 63591. I am sorta new to programming. It was originally 63591 but changed it to 1433 and realized that port is used by SQL server.

Comment: ya, this port is used by Sql Sever, well, what you need is in your web config to configure access to your database. Send me your web config, I will do it for you.. Also you mus concatenate your api/foods with the base address like this HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress+"api/foods").Result;

Comment: I only have one rep, I can not chat. Would you mind if I contacted you on linkedin?

Comment: This guy here is amazing